# Unable to connect to MSSQL PHP7 with PDO: unixODBC

Tags: php, pdo, centos, unixodbc, pdo-odbc

Firstly, I apologize because I have minimal experience with Linux so I may just not be understanding something obvious. Ultimately, I am trying to query a MSSQL database via PHP.

I have installed freetds and unixODBC. I confirmed the setup with both tsql (freetds) and isql (unixODBC) and everything works. The problem is when I try to connect from PHP using pdo using the following:
$db = new PDO('odbc:mssql', '$username','$password');

I receive a fatal PHP error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver...

Upon further inspection, I looked at my PHP info file and the available PDO drivers are: mysql and sqlite. How/where do I get the pdo odbc driver for PHP7? In the PHP documentation, it appears that the driver is included in the PHP source, but the only option I see is to use ./configure and from what I understand, that is only to compile from source.

Is there a way to add the driver to an already compiled version of PHP7? I feel like I am missing something stupid. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your OS is UBUNTU**

Install the unixODBC driver manager and Microsoft ODBC driver for Linux

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/PHP-7.0-Linux/ODBC%20install%20scripts/installodbc_ubuntu.sh
```

Run installer

```
sh installodbc_ubuntu.sh
```

Install PHP dependenceis

```
apt-get install php-pear php-dev
```

Install sqlsrv (check last version with pecl search sqlsrv)

```
pecl install sqlsrv-4.0.5
```

Install pdo_sqlsrv (check last version with pecl search sqlsrv)

```
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.5
```

Load extensions

```
echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" | sudo tee --append /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" | sudo tee --append /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

Restart PHP-FPM

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

**For windows**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

**CentOS 7**

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
exit
sudo yum update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql mssql-tools unixODBC-devel 
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
echo "extension=sqlsrv" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

or via yum look; https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm unable to use apt-get. I'm using RHEL.

Comment: i added installation for centos 7, which exact version?

Comment: Thanks! I'm on rhel version 7.4 Maipo. I am trying this out now.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to get it through the webtatic link you attached.

Comment: And if it is not Ubuntu, Suse, RH or one of the other ones MS has deemed fit you are on your own. Instead of this `sqlsrv` mess, just use `FreeTDS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Additional PHP drivers should be installed as system packages, depending of your linux distribution. For example, with Debian, you may install the required package with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-odbc
```

At least, it will be a step in the right path.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried, but it says no package available. PHP is installed as php71w and there are no available packages for odbc. However there is one for php-odbc, but it conflicts with the message: php71w-common conflicts with php-common < 7.1